# How to use sphinx-quickstart in non-interactive mode?

Tags: python-sphinx

When I run `sphinx-quickstart`, it asks me a bunch of questions.

```
> Root path for the documentation [.]:
> Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]:
> Name prefix for templates and static dir [_]:
> Project name: Foo
> Author name(s): Lone Learner
> Project version: 0.0.1
> Project release [0.0.1]:
> Project language [en]:
> Source file suffix [.rst]:
> Name of your master document (without suffix) [index]:
> Do you want to use the epub builder (y/n) [n]:
> autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/n) [n]: y
> doctest: automatically test code snippets in doctest blocks (y/n) [n]: 
> intersphinx: link between Sphinx documentation of different projects (y/n) [n]: 
> todo: write "todo" entries that can be shown or hidden on build (y/n) [n]: 
> coverage: checks for documentation coverage (y/n) [n]: 
> pngmath: include math, rendered as PNG images (y/n) [n]: 
> mathjax: include math, rendered in the browser by MathJax (y/n) [n]: 
> ifconfig: conditional inclusion of content based on config values (y/n) [n]: 
> viewcode: include links to the source code of documented Python objects (y/n) [n]:
> Create Makefile? (y/n) [y]: 
> Create Windows command file? (y/n) [y]:
```

For most of these questions, I just present enter to accept the defaults.

Here are the only four questions for which I actually provide a manual answer.

```
> Project name: Foo
> Author name(s): Lone Learner
> Project version: 0.0.1
> autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/n) [n]: y
```

Is there a way to tell `sphinx-quickstart` to use these four values and use the defaults for every other question. In other words, I want to use `sphinx-quickstart` in completely non-interactive mode. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use -q or --quiet. This option requires -p, -a and -v options (project name, author and version)

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi: Why not turn your comment into a proper answer (add `--ext-autodoc`)?

Comment: @mzjn: thanks for the advice. it's done !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sphinx-quickstart quiet mode with -q or --quiet option

This requires the following options :

- -p (for project name)
- -a (author)
- -v (version)

and you can add --ext-autodoc to automatically insert docstrings